# use Github in Eclipse without using Egit

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have recently started learning GitHub to be more collaborative with my code. I installed Egit on Eclipse and managed to get that working without too many problems but I personally find the interface quite confusing and much prefer the Git Shell or the GitHub application.

My question is how would one use Eclipse and the Git Shell or GitHub application as I can't find much on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply used them both, as long as your EGit and your Git shell knows about the same `HOME`, which isn't always automatic in Windows, since %HOME% isn't defined by default.

That matters because EGit will look for your global Git config in `%HOME%\.gitconfig`.

Beside that, any operation you will do in your Git Bash will be reflected in your Egit history.

One way to combine the two is to look for a shell plugin for Eclipse (like for instance [Wicked Shell](http://www.wickedshell.net/screenshots.html)), if you *really* don't want to switch applications between Eclipse and an external shell.

But, as [janos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641955/janos) comments, nothing prevents you to use Git Bash, EGit and GitHub app for the same repo.

> In any case, it's good to have EGit, so that he can see the state of the files in Eclipse, without having to switch to Git Bash to check status.
>   This is how I use it too: do pretty much everything in Git Bash, but profit from seeing status immediately in Eclipse

Comment: In fact he can use all 3 together: Git Bash, EGit, GitHub app. In any case, it's good to have EGit, so that he can see the state of the files in Eclipse, without having to switch to Git Bash to check status. This is how I use it too: do pretty much everything in Git Bash, but profit from seeing status immediately in Eclipse.

Comment: @janos good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use  **git bash**  (shell) instead of any kind of GUI.

a. It gives you more control over what's going on "under the hood" of Git, and than your life will be much happier.

b. It will make your trouble shooting better

c. even if at the end you will use a gui, it only wraps some shell commands together, so you better understand what the gui is actually doing.

Although Git have some unpleasent growing pains, after first few times the git bash will be super easy and understandable for you.

Some nice tutorials here: http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/

Comment: I would love to just use the git bash, I just don't understand how to use it with Eclipse without the Egit plugin.

Comment: I use git shell to version control while writing code in VS2012, it works great.

The idea of using a shell is that the source control (via git) is independat of the coding-compiling-building software.

The process should be: first init the git repository and push all source files (java, images, css, what ever you have).
Then, every time you make a change in eclipse and you are pleased with it: "commit" it. Then, after this commit, or after several commits: "push" it into the remote repository (I guess in gitHub, BitBucket etc.).

Comment: How would you choose what directory Git looks in for the source files?

Comment: What you are looking for is the command "git init".
You need to open git-bash -> go to the desired folder -> run "git init".

I suggest you first read this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository